# My developer visual stops working after declaring an object using d3-scale function

Tags: typescript, d3.js, powerbi

After finishing a part of a Power BI tutorial, the developer visual was nothing but a blank page (it ran correctly, just shows nothing). I couldn't find the problem so I started debugging. I have a test code for debugging that looks like this:

```
public update(options: VisualUpdateOptions) {
        let viewModel = this.getWievModel(options);

        console.log('Visual update', options));
        debugger;

        let debugtest = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 600]);
```

For some reason when I use the console.log and debugger **before** the 'debugtest' declaration it logs correctly, but putting it **after** the declaration, it doesn't log anything. The Visual Code doesn't drop any errors/warnings in any of the files.
The problem persists only when I use the d3-scale functions. I can't do anything if my code stops working after using d3-scale. I installed both d3@3 and d3-scale. Perhaps I installed something incorrectly or didn't declare something that is only crucial for the Power BI. Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Your mixing versions of d3 - if you use only d3@3 and d3.scale.linear (no d3-scale), does this get you any further? Not sure how a version mismatch would play out in your environment, but it seems to be a possible explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the npm packages and found out that the 'pbiviz new project' code installs the latest d3 version by default and probably this was the cause of my problem. After uninstalling the latest version (5.something) and installing the d3@3 version, fixed the problem. Probably the packages got mixed up after installing d3@3 over the latest version.